# How can I check if an MVC 3 view's model has some data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

My view is using WebGrid to display a grid.

It works good if the Model has some data but if the model comes with no data then the WebGrid gives and exception.

I tried doing a check if `Model != null` but that just let my code within the IF execute. Also tried doing a check to see `if (Model.Count() > 2)` and that just gave me a message saying `"The specified resource does not exist."`.

With either of those two conditions the code inside of the IF executed. Is there a simple way that I can check the information being passed in to see if the Model has any rows?

```
@model IEnumerable<Selftestware.Storage.Models.TestFormat>

@section content {
    <div id="content">

    @if (    Model  != null) { 

        var grid = new WebGrid(
             source: Model,
             defaultSort: "Name", 
             canPage: true, 
             canSort: true,
             rowsPerPage: 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send in List action emmty list example:

```
public ActionResult List()
{
//hear check if is null 
return View(new List<yourModel>());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static class YourWelcome{
     public static bool IsNullOrHasNullProperties(this object model){
         if(model == null) { 
             return true;
         }
         return model.GetType()
              .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance)
              .Where(propertyInfo => !propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsValueType)
              .Any(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(model,null) == null);
     }
     public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable){
         return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the answer above don't make sense for my problem. I want to do a check within the razor view to determine if there is any data passed to the model. In some cases where there is no data in the table then nothing is passed to the model. When I try to check if model is null i get messages like "resource not found".

Comment: Ok.  In your view, replace `@if(Model!=null)` with `@if(!Model.IsNullOrHasNullProperties())`.  This checks whether any of the Model's properties are null as well as if the Model is null.  So, if the Model is not null and doesn't have null properties, then it will have data...Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handled a scenaro with my webgrid when the model did not have any data.

```
if (Model.Results.Count() > 0)
 {

     <div id="grid">


        @grid.GetHtml()

     </div> 
}
else
{
    <p>No Results Found.</p>
}
```